# How to implement timeout on a running task?

Tags: ruby, networking

I need to write a ruby block that will be polling remote network service. Since, it’s network love I need to enforce several conditions:

- Timeout after X minutes if not finished
- Timeout on API call if no response

Is there an execution library or equivalent in ruby which I can use? I need to basically setup a thread to run in the background and block on it’s execution, then expect the status / return value of the thread (block) and act upon the result.

Being somewhat new to ruby //

Comment: How are you calling that network service? can you show some code to see what's exactly happening? It's important because, we can not assume how you have or going to call your services and if we come up with some example which doesn't work for your case, then it'll be a waste of time for both, you and the answerer.

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this:

```
Timeout.timeout(60) do #time is sec
  #your code    
end

rescue Timeout::Error
  #rescue code
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Timeout](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.4/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html) in Ruby's Std-lib.